# library to serialize numbers across programing language and machine

Tags: java, c

I have a program in Java that needs to write a file with integers of 8, 16, 32 and 64 bits and floating point numbers of 16, 32 and 64 bits.
This file needs to be read by a program in C (and vice-versa).
These programs are used in different type of machines, so the file needs to be independent of little or big endian.

I am looking for a library in Java and in C for doing this. The library needs to be compact, because this will be used also in a micro-controller.

note: At the moment, I am implementing the functions myself, and it works fine (so, no need to give me an ad-hoc solution).
note: I am aware that I could write the numbers in a human readable format, and use scanf to read them; I prefer not to use this solution now, because it is slower and takes more place.

Answer (score 3):

Google's [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) seem like what you're after.

Comment: It looks great, thanks! However, it is not a compact library, definitively not suited for a micro-controller I guess.
I installed and played with it, and it seems that a 32 bit number is not serialized in 4 bytes, but in a kind of decimal format, so the number 9 would be serialized in one byte, and the number 2^31 would be serialized in 12 bytes. Moreover, there is not a C version (only C++).
Are you aware of an alternative?

Comment: @David Portabella: There's [also a C version](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-c/).  Did you notice the [optimize for code size option](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/reference/java-generated.html) in the Java code generator?

Comment: thanks! I am checking out the C version. hope that the code size is small enough to put it into a microcontroller.

Answer (score 2):

On the Java side, you can just use [`DataOutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html), it's guaranteed to use big endian format aka network byte order. On the C side, you can use the [`ntohl()` and `ntohs()`](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Byte-Order.html) functions to convert network byte order to host byte order.

Comment: @David: DataOutputStream does everything, and ntohl() and ntohs()  should work for floats as well. The only problem is that they only do 16 and 32 bits, there doesn't seem to be a standard function for 64 bit values (for single-byte values, there isn't anything to do anyway).

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to use Sun's XDR format. Oddly, I don't believe Java ships with support for it, but if you look around, it's easy to find. Sun does include an XDR library with Solaris; if you're not using Solaris, it's easy to find implementations for C as well.